# Having problems making dojo 1.7.2 work

Tags: javascript, dojo, digit

I can't seem to make dojo 1.7.2 work for me. Can someone please tell me why this is not working?
http://jsfiddle.net/YApwK/22/

Answer (score 1):

The widget's are located under `dijit/`, not `digit/` - you've typed it in wrong.

You also didn't include `dojo/main`, which is required for certain common Dojo operations (like dojo.byId).  When using the new AMD modules, Dojo doesn't load very much at first.

(Also, because you don't have any CSS added, it doesn't look very nice, but this will help get you started.)

Here's the basic dijit working correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ezc7/2/

Comment: note that any dijit theme loaded in stylesheets does not apply until you set the class on and outer DOM node. (e.g. `<body class="claro">`)